# Problema con Heroku y reactjs

Tags: aplicación-web, reactjs, heroku

Estoy teniendo un problema al querer hacer `push heroku master` ya que al intentar hacer `push` me sale el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo desplegar mi app hecha con `react` en heroku?

Gracias

Comment: Hola Karkuler, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Es mejor poner el texto del error en vez de imagen por si alguien tuviera problemas viendolas o conexiones lentas. Has investigado tutoriales o buscado el error en un navegador? Has intenado algo para solucionarlo ?  Mira [ask] y [help/on-topci] para mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Chequeá que esté el **buildpack** seteado correctamente, fijate en la [documentación de heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#officially-supported-buildpacks) los soportes que le dan ellos. Y para setear, por ejemplo node, ejecutás lo siguiente:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
```